# MSSQL что быстрее. Оптимизация часто встречающихся конструкций

Tags: sql-server

У меня очень часто возникают вопросы, что в mssql быстрее, один способ, или другой.

1. `where @id is null or id = @id` или `where isnull(@id,id)=id` 
   вопрос возник потому, что операция or в mssql часто работает медленнее.
2. `where id = 1 or id = 2` или `where id in (1,2)` аналогично.

Хотелось бы в этом вопросе собрать ещё спорные решения, которые позволяют лучше оптимизировать код sql.

Comment: Я столкнулся что в 1 второе работает быстрее. Не могу понять, ошибся я, или это действительно так. По поводу 2 - я не сомневаюсь что in работает быстрее. И опыт показывает то же.

Comment: Почему вы решили, что in работает быстрее?

Comment: *Я столкнулся что в 1 второе работает быстрее* Таблица закэшилась...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `where @id is null or id = @id` или `where isnull(@id,id)=id` - работает одинаково медленно. SQL Server не может заранее предсказать результат `@id is null` и строит план со сканом всей таблицы (или индекса) и проверкой предиката для каждой записи. На объемах таблицах - одинаково быстро. На больших - одинаково медленно, причем тормозит не вычисление предиката, а IO.
2. `where id = 1 or id = 2` или `where id in (1,2)` на одной и той же таблице дает одинаковый план - они оба отображаются или в seek с набором предикатов (если есть подходящий индекс, см. ниже), или в scan, если подходящего индекса нет, или если таблица достаточно небольшая.

Запрос:

```
Select * from SomeTable 
where Id in (1,2)
```

Кусок плана:

```
<SeekPredicates>
  <SeekPredicateNew>
    <SeekKeys>
      <Prefix ScanType="EQ">
        <RangeColumns>
          <ColumnReference Database="[Test]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SomeTable]" Column="Id" />
        </RangeColumns>
        <RangeExpressions>
          <ScalarOperator ScalarString="(1)">
            <Const ConstValue="(1)" />
          </ScalarOperator>
        </RangeExpressions>
      </Prefix>
    </SeekKeys>
  </SeekPredicateNew>
  <SeekPredicateNew>
    <SeekKeys>
      <Prefix ScanType="EQ">
        <RangeColumns>
          <ColumnReference Database="[Test]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SomeTable]" Column="Id" />
        </RangeColumns>
        <RangeExpressions>
          <ScalarOperator ScalarString="(2)">
            <Const ConstValue="(2)" />
          </ScalarOperator>
        </RangeExpressions>
      </Prefix>
    </SeekKeys>
  </SeekPredicateNew>
</SeekPredicates>
```

Comment: 2. Я был уверен, что оператор in из... 10 или 100 чисел, построит двоичное дерево, и SQL не будет заниматся линейным поиском... Вижу, и правда, план идеинтичный.

Comment: А можно ли заставить список [проверять двоичным поиском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/816759/17974)?

Comment: @nick_n_a в куске плана из ответа - как раз двоичный поиск index seek (т.к. есть индекс по ID), т.к. таблица достаточно большая. Делается отдельный поиск по каждому из значений из ID. При большом количестве значений и маленькой таблице вместо этого может быть scan (т.к. он дешевле).

Comment: @nick_n_a т.е. in и or эквивалентны, оба могут стать как seek с набором предикатов, как и scan c or. на разные планы можно посмотреть, явно написав `from SomeTable WITH (FORCESEEK)` / `FORCESCAN`