# Как в MSSQL заставить проверять список двоичным поиском?

Tags: sql-server

Допустим у меня есть запись

```
select * from table1 where (id/100) in (1,5,7,22,34,40,51)
```

c проверкой порядка 100 значений.
Можно ли дать указание или переписать запрос так, что б SQL проверял не линейным поиском, а двоичным? Можно ли сделать это без создания таблицы?

Answer (score 2):

Двоичный поиск возможен только по структуре, отсортированной в порядке роста ключа. Поэтому у нас есть два пути: 1. Создать индекс по нужному нам ключу (`id/100`), чего можно достигнуть создав соответствующую виртуальную колонку и создав индекс по ней. 2. Преобразовать условие поиска так, что бы колонка осталась ни как не преобразованной. Если предположить, что id имеет целочисленный тип и  округляется при делении, то `id/100=5` должно преобразоваться в `id>=500 and id<600`.

Кроме того оптимизатор не любит IN и OR, когда они включают много значений, join обычно гораздо эффективней. Таблицу создавать при этом, разумеется, не надо, достаточно включить прямо в запрос подходящее табличное выражение. Например:

```
select *
  from table1 T
  join (values(1),(7),(22),...) X(x)
    on T.id >= X.x*100 and T.id < X.x*100+100
```

В версиях MSSQL до 2008 вместо values можно использовать `select 1 x union select 7 union ...`.

А дальше все зависит от оптимизатора, если таблица большая и по полю id есть индекс вполне возможно, что он выберет выполнение join двоичным поиском по индексу.

Comment: Попробовал я `in` поменять на `join` не получил ускорение... наверно где-то что-то упустил.

Comment: @nick_n_a А никто не сказал, что вы его получите. Просто шанс на работу по индексу вырос. В любом случае надо смотреть план выполнения. Разбираться какой объем таблицы, какой % записей из него получается по указанным условиям. смотреть какие все таки индексы и как эти индексы и данные лежат физически на диске